# sndio sio_onmove not calling back.

Tags: audio, openbsd

I'm trying to write a fullduplex test that copies audio in to audio out. sio_onmove does not get called. I have no idea why. Here's my code so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <sndio.h>

unsigned char buf[0xffff];

struct sio_hdl *hdl;

void cb(void *arg, int delta) {
 int l;
 printf("call %d\n", delta);
 for(;;) {
  l = sio_read(hdl, buf, delta);
  if(l==0) break;
  sio_write(hdl, buf, l);
 }
}

int main(void) {
 int m, i;
 struct sio_par par;
 struct sio_cap cap;

 hdl = sio_open("rsnd/0", SIO_PLAY | SIO_REC , 1);


 sio_getcap(hdl, &cap);

 sio_initpar( &par);

 par.bits = cap.enc[0].bits;
 par.bps = cap.enc[0].bps;
 par.sig = cap.enc[0].sig;
 par.le = cap.enc[0].le;
 par.msb = cap.enc[0].msb;
 par.rchan=cap.rchan[0];
 par.pchan=cap.pchan[0];
 par.rate =cap.rate[0];

 par.appbufsz = 1024;

 sio_setpar(hdl, &par);

 sio_onmove(hdl, cb, NULL);

 sio_start(hdl);

 for(;;)
  sleep(1);

}
```

I'm initializing rsnd/0 for recording and play back. The parameters I'm initializing from a getcap call. I'm then setting cb as the callback for onmove. I then start audio. From there I loop forever doing nothing

Answer (score 2):

The `sio_onmove()` call-back is called either from `sio_revents()` if non-blocking i/o is used or from blocking `sio_read()` or `sio_write()`.
As above program calls `sleep(1)` instead, the call-back is never called.

AFAIU, to do the full-duplex test, you could use blocking i/o (set to 0 last argument of the `sio_open()` function) and do the following steps:

1. call `sio_initpar()` to initialize a `sio_par` structure, as you do
2. set your preferred parameters in the `sio_par` structure
3. call `sio_setpar()` to submit them to the device. devices exposed through the server (ex. "snd/0") will accept any parameters, while raw devices (ex. "rsnd/0") pick something close to whatever the hardware supports.
4. call `sio_getpar()` to get the parameters the device accepted, this is needed to get the device buffer size
5. possibly check if they are usable by your program
6. call `sio_start()`
7. prime the play buffer by writing `par.bufsz` samples with   `sio_write()`. This corresponds to: `par.bufsz * par.pchan * par.bps` bytes.

At this stage, device starts and you could do the main-loop as with the following pseudo-code:

```
unsigned char *data;
size_t n, todo, blksz;

blksz = par.round * par.rchan * par.bps;
for (;;) {
        /* read one block */
        data = buf;
        todo = blksz;
        while (todo > 0) {
                n = sio_read(hdl, data, todo);
                if (n == 0)
                        errx(1, "failed");
                todo -= n;
                data += n;
        }
        /* write one block */
        n = sio_write(hdl, buf, blksz);
        if (n != blksz)
                errx(1, "failed");
}
```

The sio_onmove() call-back is not needed for pure audio programs. It's only useful to synchronize non-audio events (ex video, midi messages) to the audio stream.